# A wine program needs /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so on Fedora 36, what do I do?

Tags: fedora, wine, mesa

I have just installed Fedora 36 on a system, and I am trying to run Mavis Beacon Teaches Typing 15 with wine. The program worked in Fedora 35 after installing mfc42 and corefonts, but is failing in Fedora 36, apparently because /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so is missing. I checked, and /usr/lib/dri does not exist. I have reported the problem to WineHQ. What can I do? What is even going on?

Comment: you can search the internet for `iris_dri.so`

Comment: @jsotola I did try that, multiple times and ways. If you find something complete and up to date, you are greater than I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so` is provided by the 32bit version of `mesa-dri-drivers` so if you really need this one and not the 64bit version (which is in `/usr/lib64`) install the `mesa-dri-drivers.i686` package.

Comment: Noted. Will try. I am running a 32-bit prefix. Would running in a 64-bit wine prefix instead change it, you think?

Comment: You can try that too, but some older apps (and especially games) don't work with 64bit prefix. (That might have changed lately, I haven't use wine for some time.)

Comment: I tried it with 64-bit prefix, and I ran into another crash problem which I won’t detail. Installing the package you suggested and using a 32 bit prefix worked, thankfully. It also fixed another problem I had been encountering in Fedora 35, where the app would not go into full screen properly. TYJ!

Comment: I will note, though, that I’m pretty sure this application did previously work with a 64-bit prefix, and does work on 64-bit Windows XP.